# arabic italic font

Tags: jquery, css

`font-style:italic;` tilts the font to the right just like this: *my font*

In Arabic, the writing is done from right-to-left, not left-to-right. What I am trying to achieve is italicizing the font so that it is tilted to the left instead of to the right. Any suggestions? You do not have to include Arabic letters in your answer. I want something that does the opposite of `font-style:italic;` in any language.

[image]

Comment: Are you declaring text-direction:rtl?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vPLkE/ direction does not work

Comment: What font are you using ? Loading an arabic specific font will solve it since the italic will be drawn into the ttf or ie equivalent

Comment: @MarwanDoumit I use web-based fonts. and non of them do the job.

Comment: Have you actually tested this using any right-to-left fonts (e.g, Arabic or Hebrew), or are you just guessing based on what you've seen for Latin fonts?

Comment: _طبعاً جربته_ .. does that satisfy your needs @duskwuff?

Comment: try what you are doing with amiri; it has a "slanted" version...which i'm assuming is italic. http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/amiri

Comment: @shnisaka Please consider looking at my (updated) answer again. It might be something to work with. Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something called `skew` in the CSS transformation declaration:

```
.fontToTransform {
    font-size: 40px;
    transform: skewX(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(15deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(15deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(15deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(15deg);
}
```

This will get you out of the hassle of actually manipulating the font itself. This will transform the whole block your text is in tho. You might need some kind of validation to check each line-break and separate them to be new tags each time. So as this might not be a real solution, you might take it into consideration if you want to shear shorter (single-line) text.

***Edit***

This is veeeery far fetched but here's a dirty example that finds out the individual lines in your text block and puts each of them in a new `span`, what will cause each line to be separately styled with the `skewX` styling. Here you go:

**CSS**

```
#fontTransform {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

#fontTransform span {
    display: block;
    transform: skewX(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(15deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(15deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(15deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(15deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <p id="fontTransform">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = document.getElementById('fontTransform');
    var t = d.innerHTML;
    var w = t.split(' ');

    var lines = [];

    d.innerHTML = w[0];
    var height = d.clientHeight;

    var tmp_line = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + ' ' + w[i];

        tmp_line[tmp_line.length] = w[i];

        if (d.clientHeight > height) {
            height = d.clientHeight;
            console.log(w[i-1]);

            delete tmp_line[tmp_line.length-1];
            lines[lines.length] = tmp_line;
            tmp_line = [];
        }
    }

    // Destroy d.innerHTML
    d.innerHTML = '';
    var tmp_html = '';

    // Refill the lines within spans
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length-1; i++) {
        tmp_html = '<span>';
        for (var x = 0; x < lines[i].length-1; x++) {
            tmp_html = tmp_html + lines[i][x] + ' ';
        }
        tmp_html = tmp_html.trim();
        tmp_html = tmp_html + '</span>';

        d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + tmp_html;
    }
});
```

You might consider using jQuery's `resize()` binding to update the blocks of text that have percentile widths. Also I'm not sure what happens with very long words that won't fit in one line. Not that this might actually happen, but keep in mind it's not tested and might cause words to get lost. Really need to do more testing for actual publishing.

Comment: Note that the results of using a `skew` transformation on text will be significantly worse in appearance than using an actual italic variant.

Comment: In WebKit it performs very well tho. But I can imagine it might render many (complexer) fonts to look ugly. Also note that skew will mess up in multi-line blocks. It's purely to show possibilities I guess as `italic` is a whole new set of drawings in a font-file and forced CSS italic is always either failing fully (browser support issues) or looking very messy.

Comment: It depends entirely on the font you're transforming. Some will look kind of okay (particularly at larger sizes), but some will look pretty awful.

Answer (score 4):

As a fellow RTL language user I feel your pain :)

How about using an Arabic webfont and importing it to your CSS?
[Amiri](http://www.amirifont.org/) is an open web font that has the proper typographic slanting for Arabic naskh script. It's even hosted on the google CDN!

Then you could just do:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/amiri.css);
.myItalic{
   font-family: 'Amiri', serif;   
   font-style: italic; 
 }
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/G5FuS/)

If this font isn't to your liking, you can use other other web fonts. [Here are some](http://www.google.com/webfonts/earlyaccess) to test with. If non of those work for you - I guess you can find a font that is to your liking, alter its italic version and embed it on your page in the same fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with Allendar (from above)

Can be done in CSS3 easily. No need for JavaScript...at all.

Here's your answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style type="text/css">    
      .skewTheFont {
        transform: skewX(10deg);
        -webkit-transform: skewX(10deg);
        -moz-transform: skewX(10deg);
        font-size: 60px;
        font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;

      }
    </style>
    <!-- Style ends here -->  
</head>  

<body>
    <p class="skewTheFont">Arabic Font</p>


</body>

</html>
```

However, this is supported in FF, IE10 and Chrome (not for < IE10)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this with the font-style property. See page here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp. I'm not sure if there are Arabic fonts out there that might italicize in the opposite direction. If there are, they probably aren't widely supported.

Comment: Wasn't paying attention to what I was typing. I AM a fool.. Good catch.

Answer (score -1):

dear there are two things that i used to slice wajbah project. Use direction rtl in the code as:

```
dir="rtl"
```

after that the content which you want to show to the right hand side use `float right`.

It will carry out your problem.

Try it and reply it please.

Comment: The question is not about RTL layout. Please read it more carefully.

Comment: Name the font family you are using in your web page??