# Limit text by number of lines in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea box which echos out 'bio' - 'bio' is text content from my database.

I also have a css box next to this text area and was wondering how you could limit the text to just three lines and then carry on underneath the `CSS` box.

Here is a diagram:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|                  |   Bio Content Goes Here
|                  |   blah, blah, blah, blah     
- - - - - - - - - -    blah, blah, blah, blah  
Content carrys on here, here, here and here etc.
Content carrys on here, here, here and here etc.
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with php/mysql, and everything to do with CSS.

Comment: @Daedalus well not really because someone on here might suggest that the best way to do this is to use a php script like thus: <?php $str = $profile['public_email'];

$max = 18;

if(strlen($str) > $max) {
   $str = substr($str, 0, $max) . '...';
} ?>

Comment: Exactly. Just control the box size and it's overflow to hidden. If you specifically want the "lines" to be counted, you need todo some regular expressions, but might still be tricky.

Comment: @JamesPale limiting the string won't get your amount of "lines" tho. It will just brutally cut off your text.

Comment: not even counting lines. it also depends on font settings on the client browser, exactly which font is being used for display, blah blah blah. this is NOT something you can do reliably on the server without heavy client involvement. css with overflow: hidden is your best bet.

Comment: how would someone get this effect in css? i don't think its possible, it surely isn't an overflow matter? if the text area starts from where the css box is then no amount of overflow or padding is gona prevent the text being overlapped by the css box.

Comment: @JamesPale Yes, really.  There's no other way to do it.

Comment: Check my answer in this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348014/arabic-italic-font/15348218?noredirect=1#comment21687066_15348218 Here I show an example of how to count the amount of lines used inside a `<tag>` by literally counting the lengths of the textblocks with JavaScript. Purely looks at the `main.js`. The skewing CSS has nothing todo with this question ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Answer (score 10):

You could try this:

```
.yourBox {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: X;
    max-height: X*N
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    .yourBox {
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: N; /* number of lines to show */
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    }
}
```

From the duplicate question: [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Comment: Can we modify it to add ... when it is removing extra lines?